# Re-setting perms on RPM's does not seem to work

Tags: files, security, rpm, verification

I am using RPM for file verification. What I do is run

```
rpm -Va
```

to get a list of files that have been changed. Then I run

```
rpm -qf
```

to get the package name the file belongs to. Finally I run

```
rpm --setperms <pkgname>
```

This runs without error but does not seem to do its job as when I kickoff a new verification it returns the same list of files. Any reasons/caveats as to why this may not always work as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without details on what is failing, who knows, as some of the verifications will always fail and can never be fixed, if for example `/etc/aliases` has been modified to point `root` mail elsewhere:

```
% rpm -qf /etc/aliases
setup-2.8.14-20.el6_4.1.noarch
% rpm -V setup
S.5....T.  c /etc/aliases
%
```

In this case the file size differs (which a `--setperms` would do nothing to fix), the digest differs (again, `--setperms` is unrelated), and the mtime differs, which yet again `--setperms` will not do anything for.

However, permissions certainly can be broken and fixed with `--setperms`.

```
% sudo chmod 7001 /etc/aliases
% ls -l /etc/aliases
---S--S--t. 1 root root 1542 Aug  1  2014 /etc/aliases
% rpm -V setup
SM?....T.  c /etc/aliases
% sudo rpm --setperms setup
% rpm -V setup             
S.5....T.  c /etc/aliases
% ls -l /etc/aliases       
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1542 Aug  1  2014 /etc/aliases
%
```

Note the second column for "mode", and how the digest check failed given that the permissions were pooched.

(A wrapper around `rpm -V` might be handy, to verbosify this quite cryptic output...)

Comment: OK. After looking at most of the failed files, they were mostly the size, digest or date/time. So that makes sense. Thank you.